# Why is R not recognizing my object in for loop?

Tags: r, for-loop, initialization, tidyverse

I am trying to separately screen different grouped variables in a dataset for bad recordings and outliers using a two-pass method.  I want to do this screening for each variable separately.  I tried to run a for loop and use tidyverse language, anticipating a list of dataframes, but got an error message. Here is an example:

```
require(tidyverse)

# make the example dataframe
factor1 <- c("yes", "no","yes","no","no", "yes")
factor2 <- c("Female","Female","Male","Male", "Male", "Female")
a <- sample(1:100, 6, replace=TRUE)
b <- sample(1:100, 6, replace=TRUE)
c <- sample(1:100, 6, replace=TRUE)
d <- sample(1:100, 6, replace=TRUE)
e <- sample(1:100, 6, replace=TRUE)
simpledata <- data.frame(factor1, factor2, a, b, c, d, e)

#list of variable names to loop over
simple_vars = c("a","b","c","d","e")
   
#initialize list to store results in     
simplelist <- vector(mode="list", length=length(simple_vars))

for(i in simple_vars){
    simplelist[[i]] <<- simpledata %>%
    group_by(factor1, factor2) %>%
    filter(.data[[i]] < 5*median(.data[[i]])) %>%
    filter(between(.data[[i]], mean(.data[[i]])-3*sd(.data[[i]]),
                mean(.data[[i]])+3*sd(.data[[i]])))
}
```

I get the following error: `"Error in simplelist[[i]] <<- simpledata %>% group_by(factor1, factor2) %>%  :  object 'simplelist' not found"`.  Except I can see 'simplelist' in my environment window!  What is going wrong here?

Also, if there is a more elegant way to meet my overall goal using tidyverse notation and transmute_at or something (there probably is), I would be happy to hear about it, but my question is why R doesn't recognize the list I initialized.

Comment: Use `simplelist[[i]] <-` instead of `simplelist[[i]] <<-`. The use of `<<-` is rarely justified anyway, more often an indication of improper function architecture and scope-breach. In this case, it is both meaningless (code inside the `for` loop is in the same exact scope as outside of `for`) and, as you now see, counter-productive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<<-` operator is setting a global variable but you don't need to. Also, you can create the initial list of zero size and add entries in the for loop.

```
require(tidyverse)

# make the example dataframe
factor1 <- c("yes", "no","yes","no","no", "yes")
factor2 <- c("Female","Female","Male","Male", "Male", "Female")
a <- sample(1:100, 6, replace=TRUE)
b <- sample(1:100, 6, replace=TRUE)
c <- sample(1:100, 6, replace=TRUE)
d <- sample(1:100, 6, replace=TRUE)
e <- sample(1:100, 6, replace=TRUE)
simpledata <- data.frame(factor1, factor2, a, b, c, d, e)

#list of variable names to loop over
simple_vars = c("a","b","c","d","e")

#initialize list to store results in     
simplelist <- vector(mode="list")

for(i in simple_vars){
    simplelist[[i]] <- simpledata %>%
    group_by(factor1, factor2) %>%
    filter(.data[[i]] < 5*median(.data[[i]])) %>%
    filter(between(.data[[i]], mean(.data[[i]])-3*sd(.data[[i]]),
            mean(.data[[i]])+3*sd(.data[[i]])))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you forgot to name the elements of `simplelist` the same way they appear in `simple_vars`. So when for() pass the value "a" to simplelist[["a"]] is problably rising an error, because you do not have an element in `simplelist` that have this name. The other source of your error, are the assignment symbol, you using the special case (`<<-`) in the wrong spot.

```
factor1 <- c("yes", "no","yes","no","no", "yes")
factor2 <- c("Female","Female","Male","Male", "Male", "Female")
a <- sample(1:100, 6, replace=TRUE)
b <- sample(1:100, 6, replace=TRUE)
c <- sample(1:100, 6, replace=TRUE)
d <- sample(1:100, 6, replace=TRUE)
e <- sample(1:100, 6, replace=TRUE)
simpledata <- data.frame(factor1, factor2, a, b, c, d, e)

#list of variable names to loop over
simple_vars = c("a","b","c","d","e")

#initialize list to store results in     
simplelist <- list("a" = "", "b" = "", "c" = "", "d" = "", "e" = "")

for(i in simple_vars){
  simplelist[[i]] <- simpledata %>%
    group_by(factor1, factor2) %>%
    filter(.data[[i]] < 5*median(.data[[i]])) %>%
    filter(between(.data[[i]], mean(.data[[i]])-3*sd(.data[[i]]),
                   mean(.data[[i]])+3*sd(.data[[i]])))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I appreciate your idea of naming the items in the list to match the iteration in the for loop, but I don't think it is necessary--the <<- operator alone seemed to be the problem!